# The Dirac distribution on a manifold $M$ is a smooth manifold in $C^1(M)^*$, what is its dimension?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

How to prove that the Dirac distribution on a manifold is a smooth manifold in $C^1(M)^*$.

Let $M_1= \delta_{x_i}$, $x_i \in M$. For $\|f\|_{C^1(M)} \leq 1$, the distance on $M_1$ is defined by $$
\operatorname{dist}(\sigma, \hat{\sigma})=\sup _f|(\sigma, f)-(\hat{\sigma}, f)|
.$$
Then how to prove the Dirac distribution on a manifold $M$ is a smooth manifold in $C^1(M)^*$, and what is its dimension? Is this dimension dependent on the dimension of the manifold $M$? I have no idea on this problem, could you give me some hints or recommend me some lectures on it?  I have not learned many knowledges on differential geometry, I met this when reading the min-max scheme in PDE on manifold, which is in [Section3.1](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410141).

Comment: If you refer to Corollary 3.3, the authors never say that the Dirac mass $\delta_x$, for some $x$ fixed, is a manifold. They say that the set $M_1 = \{\delta_x \mid x \in M\}$ is a (sub)manifold (of $C^1(M)^*$). This is clear from the fact that we have an embedding $M \to C^1(M)^*$ given by $x \mapsto \delta_x$ whose image is exactly $M_1$ by definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have another question. They set $M_1(\varepsilon):=M_1$ . And $M_k=\sum_{i=1}^k t_i \delta_{x_i}$ with $\sum_i t_i=1$, for $j<k$, $d_j(\sigma)=\operatorname{dist}\left(\sigma, M_j\right), \sigma \in M_k$, then for $\varepsilon>0$ and $2 \leq j \leq k$, define $M_j(\varepsilon)=\left\{\sigma \in M_j: d_{j-1}(\sigma)>\varepsilon\right\}.$ Then they said element of $M_j(\varepsilon)$ can be smoothly parameterized by $4 j$ coordinates locating the points $x_i$ 's and by $j-1$ coordinates identifying the numbers $t_i$ 's.

Comment: At first I think this $4j$ depends on the dimension 4 of the manifold, but I find another paper using this notation on surface https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219199708002776?journalCode=ccm, which also said that element of $M_j(\varepsilon)$ can be smoothly parameterized by $4 j$ coordinates locating the points $x_i$ 's, I wonder how to calculate this $4j$? I tried multiple times but failed.

Comment: They said this is a corollary of Lemma3.2, which said that let $j \in\{2, \ldots, k\}$. Then there exists $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small with the following property. If $\sigma \in M_j(\varepsilon), \sigma=\sum_{i=1}^j t_i \delta_{x_i}$, then there holds
$
t_i \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} ; \quad \operatorname{dist}\left(x_i, x_l\right) \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} ; \quad i, l=1, \ldots, j, i \neq l .
$
I can't see why this Lemma implies $4j$.

Comment: This is a totally different question, that you should post in another question, with explicit references + what you have tried so that people who have time (not me today unfortunately) can try to help you

Comment: Thanks! @Didier , I will post another question.