# Linear combination of Dirac distribution on a manifold $M$ as a smooth manifold in $C^1(M)^*$, question about its dimension.

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

I have not learned many knowledges on differential geometry, I met this when trying to read the min-max scheme in PDE on manifold, which is in [Section3.1](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410141).

Let $M_1= \delta_{x_i}$, $x_i \in M$. For $\|f\|_{C^1(M)} \leq 1$, the distance on $M_1$ is defined by $$
\operatorname{dist}(\sigma, \hat{\sigma})=\sup _f|(\sigma, f)-(\hat{\sigma}, f)|
.$$
Didier in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794362/the-dirac-distribution-on-a-manifold-m-is-a-smooth-manifold-in-c1m-wha) kindly taught me that by the embedding $M \rightarrow C^1(M)^*$ given by $x \mapsto \delta_x$, $M_1$ is a smooth manifold in $C^1(M)^*$.
Then they set $M_1(\varepsilon):=M_1$ . And $M_k=\sum_{i=1}^k t_i \delta_{x_i}$ with $\sum_i t_i=1$, and for $j<k$, $d_j(\sigma)=\operatorname{dist}\left(\sigma, M_j\right), \sigma \in M_k$, then for $\varepsilon>0$ and $2 \leq j \leq k$, define $$M_j(\varepsilon)=\left\{\sigma \in M_j: d_{j-1}(\sigma)>\varepsilon\right\}.$$ Then they said element of $M_j(\varepsilon)$ can be smoothly parameterized by $4 j$ coordinates locating the points $x_i$ 's and by $j-1$ coordinates identifying the numbers $t_i$ 's.

This is a corollary of [Lemma3.2](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410141), which said that

**Lemma 3.2 Let $j \in\{2, \ldots, k\}$. Then there exists $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small with the following property. If $\sigma \in M_j(\varepsilon), \sigma=\sum_{i=1}^j t_i \delta_{x_i}$, then there holds
$$
t_i \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} ; \quad \operatorname{dist}\left(x_i, x_l\right) \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} ; \quad i, l=1, \ldots, j, i \neq l .
$$**

At first I think this $4j$ depends on the dimension 4 of the manifold, but I find another paper using this notation on surface, which also said that it is $4 j$ [EXISTENCE RESULT FOR THE MEAN FIELD PROBLEM ON RIEMANN SURFACES OF ALL GENUSES](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219199708002776?journalCode=ccm), I wonder how to calculate this $4 j$.

Comment: have you walked through the proof of Lem 3.2? Cor 3.3 suggests that the details are there. Is your question how they know the dimension is $5j-1$ and where the $4j$ and $j-1$ components come from?

Comment: Yes! I thought it's $4j$ because the manifold's dimension is 4 and they have $j$ summation, but I saw a paper which studied a similar question on surface https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219199708002776?journalCode=ccm , in Cor4.3 they also said it's $4j$, is it $2j$?